# Porque no se muestran los valores del json en mi controlador de asp net core 2.1

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-core

porque no se muestran los valores de json en el controlador en asp net core 2.1.
aparentemente los datos son enviados correctamente al action del controlador pero cuando hago debug no se muestran los datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hago debug en el controlador pero no aparece ni un dato

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación pongo con mas detalle el código.

Create.cshtml

```
$("#finalizar").click(function () {
            var envio = "{Fecha: '12-12-1900',ListadoDetalle: [{IdeProducto:'1',Precio:'11',Cantidad:'1'}]}";
             var json = eval("(" + envio + ")");

            $.ajax({
                 async: false,//this makes the ajax-call blocking
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 url: '@Url.Action("GuardarVenta", "Pedidos")',
                 data: JSON.stringify(json),
                 type: "POST",
                 success: function (response) {
                     alertify.alert(response);
                     valid = response.valid;
                 },
                 error: function (error) {
                     alertify.alert(error);
                 }
             });
         });//fin de botonfinalizar
```

PedidosController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GuardarVenta(DateTime Fecha, List<Detalle> ListadoDetalle)
        {
            string mensaje = "regreso";
            return Json(mensaje);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a crear un **nuevo Modelo** (`ModeloJson.cs`) que represente los **datos Json** que envías a la Acción del Controlador.

```
public class ModeloJson
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public List<Detalle> ListadoDetalle { get; set; }
}
```

Y en la Acción `GuardarVenta(...)`, **recepciona** los datos a través de este nuevo Modelo con el atributo `[FromBody]`.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GuardarVenta([FromBody] ModeloJson ListadoDetalle)
    {
        string mensaje = "regreso";
        return Json(mensaje);
    }
```

Te debería funcionar perfectamente, aun así indica por favor el código de la página (debería ser Ajax) desde donde envías los datos Json hacia la Acción del Controlador.

Comment: gracias, hice lo que me dijiste por fin trajo los datos